# Cannot resolve setLatestEventInfo the sdk version i am using is 23

Tags: android, android-studio

```
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.stat_sample,
                        getText(R.string.new_friend_request_exist),
                        System.currentTimeMillis());

Intent i = new Intent(this, UnApprovedFriendList.class);
i.putExtra(FriendInfo.FRIEND_LIST, tmp);

PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
        i, 0);

notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, getText(R.string.new_friend_request_exist),
        "You have new friend request(s)",
        contentIntent);
```

What is wrong in the above code?.............................................................................................................................................

Comment: setLatestEventInfo cannot be resolved

Answer (score 2):

ya because it is deprecated method.
you can use

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                    this);
            myNotification = builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.yourstring)
                    .setTicker(notificationText).setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentTitle(getText(R.string.title))
                    .setContentText(notificationText).build();
```

Comment: There must also be a way without NotificationCompat - anyone knows how?